# Proper resource locations for software under /usr/local (var data like log)

Tags: logs, directory-structure

I'm trying to put together a small piece of software, and I wanted to know the appropriate place to put various items if I'm setting to use /usr/local.

For example, under /usr/local I will have:

bin
etc
lib

But what about variable data like logs?  Does they still go to /var/log?  It seems weird to pollute /var/log with something non-standard running out of /usr/local.

What about other input data that isn't considered runnable code?  I noticed that some software uses /usr/local/PKG-NAME/ to store this kind of data.

Oh and I also have to put a lockfile somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Look at how other 3rd-party software does this on your system.

On OpenBSD, 3rd-party packages install under `/usr/local` but uses `/var` for variable data (since that's what `/var` is for).  Some packages create `/var/pkgname` directories (like `mysql`) and some may create `/var/log/pkgname` (like `ConsoleKit` seems to do) depending on what type of data it needs to store under `/var`.

For private and local (small, datawise) projects, I see no real reason to not use `/usr/local/var` except with the important caveat that `/`, `/usr` or `/usr/local` (if these separate mount points from `/var`) may possibly fill up if the application produces huge datasets.  If `/` fills up, this will possibly prevent the system from functioning properly (this is why `/var` is usually on its own filesystem). If `/usr/local` fills up, this will prevent installing further software.